# BASH script to create SQL statement ignore last column

Tags: sql, bash, shell, ifs

I am trying to create a bash script that will generate an SQL CREATE TABLE statement from a CSV file.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the user provided a CSV file
if [ $# -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "No CSV file provided."
    exit 1
fi

# Check if the CSV file exists
if [ ! -f $1 ]
then
    echo "CSV file does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

# Get the table name from the CSV file name
table_name=$(basename $1 .csv)

# Extract the header row from the CSV file
header=$(head -n 1 $1)

# Split the header row into column names
IFS=',' read -r -a columns <<< "$header"

# Generate the PostgreSQL `CREATE TABLE` statement
echo "CREATE TABLE $table_name ("
for column in "${columns[@]}"
do
    echo "  $column TEXT,"
done
echo ");"
```

If I have a CSV file with three columns(aa,bb,cc), the generated statement does not have the last column for some reason.

Any idea what could be wrong?

If I do:

```
for a in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$a"
done
```

I am getting:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

But when add something into the string:

```
for a in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo "$a SOMETHING"
done
```

I get:

```
aaa SOMETHING
bbb SOMETHING
 SOMETHING
```

Thanks.

Comment: For debugging, I would first focus on your second example, using the variable `array`, as it is simpler as the original SQL problem. Having said this, I must say that I can **not** reproduce the behaviour you are describing, as you can see [in my screenshot](https://www.4shared.com/s/fGXh3LDnxku). In your code, the last element of `array` must be empty; show a screenshot which proves that in your case it's different!

Comment: @user1934428 https://ibb.co/gSN45RF

Comment: This is **not** the simple example of the `array` from my screenshot, which you claimed wouldn't work either. Try to reproduce the simple case first, before proceeding to the more complicated one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your csv file has a '\r`
Try the next block for reproducing the problem.

```
printf -v header "%s,%s,%s\r\n" "aaa" "bbb" "ccc"
IFS=',' read -r -a columns <<< "$header"
echo "Show array"
for a in "${columns[@]}"; do echo "$a"; done
echo "Now with something extra"
for a in "${columns[@]}"; do echo "$a SOMETHING"; done
```

You should remove the '\r', what can be done with

```
IFS=',' read -r -a columns < <(tr -d '\r' <<< "${header}")
```

Comment: header=$(head -n 1 test.csv | tr -d '[[:space:]]') solve that. Thanks for hint.